# How to get at the role created by cloudformation when creating a lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

Here is my lambda definition in cloudformation:

```
CommandTopic:
   Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
   Properties:
      DisplayName: 'ns-poc-commands'
      TopicName: 'ns-poc-commands'

SendMessage:
   Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
   Properties:
      CodeUri: send_lambda
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      FunctionName: send_message
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 15
      Policies:
        - SNSPublishMessagePolicy:
            TopicName: !Ref CommandTopic
```

Now I want my lambda to be able to publish messsages back to the CommandTopic and in order to this I need an access policy on the topic which allows this:

```
 CommandTopicPolicy:
   Type: AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy
   Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
         Version: '2012-10-17'
         Statement:
          - Sid: SnsTopicPolicy
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: sns:Publish
            Resource: !Ref CommandTopic
            Condition:
              ArnEquals:
                aws:SourceArn: !Ref SendMessage
          - Sid: SnsRolePolicy
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: !Ref SendMessageRole     # -- 1
            Action: sns:Publish
            Resource: !Ref CommandTopic
      Topics:
        - Ref: CommandTopic
```

So I need to give the topic a directive to allow the user assigned to my lambda to post messages to it.

Consider line referenced by --1. As it is it doesn't work as that reference is not available.

So I don't know how to access that role that was created... I'd prefer not to have to create the role myself as that just makes things more complicated and it's more work...

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to simply modify the Lambda function's IAM policy to include sns:Publish on the SNS topic ARN? Rather than work backwards from an SNS resource policy?

Comment: You need that, and you _also_ need to add the access policy to the sns topic

Comment: and besides, I do have that: the SendMessageLambda has an embedded SNSPublishMessagePolicy

Comment: I should use SAM and SNS more ;-) Can you create the IAM role for the Lambda function as an explicit resource in the template, rather than have SAM auto-gen it, and then simply reference `Role: !GetAtt SendMessageRole.Arn` in the Lambda function and topic policy? Or perhaps work out what SAM's auto-gen naming strategy is so you can infer the policy resource name or policy ARN?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation you have to pass a role ARN as the principal value. Right now you are trying to pass the role name (`!Ref SendMessageRole`).

> If your Principal element in a role trust policy contains an ARN that
>   points to a specific IAM role

For further informations check the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html)

To tackle the second problem that the reference doesn't exists I would suggest to add a `DependsOn` option to your `CommandTopicPolicy` resource.

It might then look as the following

```
  CommandTopicPolicy:
    Type: AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy
    DependsOn:
      - SendMessage
    Properties:
      Topics:
        - Ref: CommandTopic
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Sid: SnsTopicPolicy
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: sns:Publish
            Resource: !Ref CommandTopic
            Condition:
              ArnEquals:
                aws:SourceArn: !GetAtt SendMessage.Arn
          - Sid: SnsRolePolicy
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: !GetAtt SendMessageRole.Arn
            Action: sns:Publish
            Resource: !Ref CommandTopic
```